# Macro code in Excel VBA isn't running as expected

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro where EXCEL does the following :

- Changes the data in A1 , B1, C1, etc... to a specific date format (dd-mm-yyyy)
- Uses the DATEDIFF function to calculate the days between the values in A1 and B1 and between A1 and C1
- Puts the results of that DateDIFF function in another cell

I keep getting stranges values and reset of my function

This is the code i'm using now but i keep getting errors :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Range("A1:A5000").NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
Range("B1:B5000").NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim n As Variant
Dim Range("A1:A5000") As Date
Dim Range("B1:B5000") As Date

n = DateDiff("d", Range("A1:A5000"), Range("B1:B5000"))
n = Range("C1:C5000")

End Sub
```

UPDATE :

The error in VBA = TYPE MISMATCH.

A little more explanation for this :

1. User copies dates in to the first 3 colums (A, B, C)
2. My Macro (script) has to change these values into a standard format (dd-mm-yyyy)
3. Another Button or script has to calculate the days between : 
   A and B 
   B and C
   A and C
4. The days calculated by 3 had to be put in another column (H or something) so it can be reported.

I'm sorry if i was not that clear, it's my first time using Stackoverflow.

Regards,

Comment: Are you trying to do a A1 - B1 datediff or the whole range?

Comment: The last paragraph you type indicates there should be more code at the end? But there isn't any - you can use the [edit] link to add that code. Also, please include the *error* messages you get and indicate *which line of code* is triggering each error. This is not enough information to understand what problem(s) you're having.

Comment: I'm trying to DateDiFF the whole range

Answer (score 0):

Without further info and assuming your goal... this might help you:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim n As Long 'it will give you a number
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim C As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName") 'change this to the actual sheet name
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'last row on column A
        For Each C In .Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
            C.Offset(0, 2) = DateDiff("d", C, C.Offset(0, 1))
        Next C
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```